# GWT Hide A Cell of a Grid Panel

Tags: java, gwt, properties, grid, visible

Is it possible to hide a complete cell of a Grid Panel in java GWT?

Now I explain my question in detail:
I have a grid with some labels and textboxes, I want to hide the middle label and textbox, but when I set the *visible* property as **false** , it hides the 2 objects but it leaves the space between the 2 rows.  How can I do to set those objects visible and the other objects to move up so there is no blank space between the two rows?

GWT Design View

http://s11.postimg.org/jc05zgjkj/gwt_grid_01.png

```
lblName.setVisible(false);
txtbxName.setVisible(false);
```

View after apply the  *visible* property to **false**

http://s15.postimg.org/dnkd2927v/gwt_grid_02.png

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Have you tried using grid.removeRow(row)?

Answer (score 1):

To hide the whole row you can use:

```
grid.getRowFormatter().setVisible(rowIndex, false);
```

Comment: Still there is space in between while loading such grid, but changed that problem by setting this property to that element. 
position: absolute,

Answer (score 1):

Hope you need to hide element from DOM:
Can be done by changing row elements Display property.

**Sample Code ***

```
Grid g = new Grid();
int rowNumberToHideFromDom;
g.getRowFormatter().getElement(rowNumberToHideFromDom).getStyle().setDisplay(Display.NONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the HTML table generated in the browser by your GWT code (preferably when visible is set to false). You may see something like this:

```html
<tbody>
  <!-- ... -->
  <tr> <!-- hidden row -->
    <td><!-- hidden widget --></td>
    <td><!-- hidden widget --></td>
    <td></td> <!-- The single space within the td element bears importance! -->
  </tr>
  <!-- ... -->
</tbody>
```

That empty space is padded because the hidden row still contains one or more td elements that have some whitespace content.

This is caused by the Grid widget's implementation of "empty" cells: when you do not set any content to a Grid's cell, or clear out previously set content, the implementation practically insterts a non-breaking space (nbsp) into that cell. (Have a look at the Grid source: addRows(), clearCell() and createCell().)

This default behaviour can be tricked by setting the innerHTML of the empty cells manually to an empty string:

```
grid.setHTML(2, 3, "");
```

Also, I guess that the grid.removeRow(row) workaround mentioned in united's comment may also work, although removing the whole row is a bit more radical If you intend to show the hidden row again, you better stick to solving this by setting empty strings into empty cells.